# js and css transformed 3d slowing down my browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am having a problem with the HTML page running smoothly. I have 5 CSStransform3d implementations and I believe I am slowing down the page. Currently I use an easing scroller (when you click on a nav link it eases in and eases out to the next location). Is there anyway to preload these at all? The scrolling was working fine before I implemented these scrolls and now there is a 2 second delay everytime I click a link. I get this script in the firebug settings which tipped me off:

```
  <html class=" js csstransforms3d js csstransforms3d js csstransforms3d js csstransforms3d
  csstransforms3d js csstransforms3d js csstransforms3d js csstransforms3d
  csstransforms3d js csstransforms3d js csstransforms3d js csstransforms3d lang="en">
```

I use this js for the scrolling:

```
 $(function () { //this is the way to run your code at the DOM Ready event

$('a').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500);
    return false;
});
```

});

but the css transforms along with js and jquery are more complex which I think is slowing the page down. If you need me to paste the CSS/JS/jQuery script in here I can, but just wanted to see if there is anyway to speed up the scrolling because as of right now I click a link and 2 seconds go by, and then it starts to scroll to where I need it to (this is all in one webpage).

Comment: You mean there is 2 seconds between time you click a link and scrolling animation start? And why so much "csstransforms3d js" classes for html?

Comment: It would be nice to see it working on a fiddle.

Comment: what should I place the web page in to make it run faster then if not an HTML page?

Comment: You animate both `html` and `body`. Does this make sense?